# How best to package files on base install directory of electron

Tags: package, electron, production

I have been trying to make an electron app that relies on a third-party executable . Whenever I try bundling the app, the executable gets bundled with the rest of the app in asar format, making it impossible to access from outside the electron\node environent.

My question is how should I setup my environment or build config to achieve an installation where the third-party executable is on the root of the installed app?

PS: I am using electron-builder and a two-package.json format and I am getting a 
successful build minus this caveat.

Here's my build config

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.toutici.asd",
    "asar": true,
    "directories": {
      "app": "./app",
      "buildResources": "./build",
      "output": "./dist"
    },
    "electronDownload": {
      "cache": ".electron",
      "verifyChecksum": true
    },
    "electronVersion": "1.7.11",
    "fileAssociations": {
      "ext": "asd",
      "icon": "./www/assets/icon/win/icon.ico"
    },
    "productName": "Android SMS Delimiter",
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.productivity",
      "target": [
        "dmg",
        "mas"
      ],
      "icon": "./build/icon.icns"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 110,
          "y": 150
        },
        {
          "x": 240,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "deb": {
      "compression": "gz",
      "icon": "./build/background.png"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "apk",
        "deb",
        "rpm",
        "snap",
        "tar.gz",
        "zip"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "ia32"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": true,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": false,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "runAfterFinish": true,
      "installerIcon": "./build/icon.ico"
    },
    "portable": {
      "requestExecutionLevel": "user"
    },
    "squirrelWindows": {
      "iconUrl": "./build/icon.ico",
      "loadingGif": "./build/install-spinner.gif",
      "msi": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: You may want to look into the [extraFiles or extraResources](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extraresources) option

Comment: `extraFiles` worked for me. Please post it as the answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

> extraFiles

config property to the *electron-builder.json* seems to solve the problem.

E.g.:

```
  "extraFiles": [
      {
         "from": "../../CHANGELOG.md",
          "to": "."
      }
    ],
```

See also electron configuration docu: https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extrafiles